# What is Columbus Reverse Engineering?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, design-patterns, statistics, reverse-engineering

I am studying  a research  paper on design  pattern. In the paper,they used an approach  called Columbus Reverse  Engineering.
I am not really  sure what this is. Is it a Machine  learning  algorithm  or any statistical  method?
And why is it used to detect design pattern?
I mean why do we need to detect design pattern?  What is the motive?
TIA

Comment: Please link to the paper.

Comment: From the description, I think it is a framework. Within the paper there is no obvious clue about the use of ML. This is the paper I found: http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~beszedes/research/beszedesa_columbus_step2005.pdf.